# Is there MIcrosoft API to find out if a start up application is enabled/disabled and it's level of impact?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, startup

I am looking for an API that lists all the startup applications in Windows, and can return whether each application is enabled or disabled at startup and it's level of impact.

These settings and the startup apps referred to are found in Settings->Apps->Startup.

I have found PowerShell and command line commands to list some (but not all) of the start up apps. However I am looking for a way to do so programmatically in C# so I do not need to execute a script to list the startup apps. The commands also are limited to the name, command, and location. They do not show whether the startup app is enabled/disabled and the level of impact.

These are the commands I have used to list some of the start up apps.
Powershell: Get-CimInstance Win32_StartupCommand | Select-Object Name, command, Location, User | Format-List

Command Line: wmic startup get caption,command

Comment: The state of these applications / services is stored in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run` (the LSB set to `2` means Enabled and (usually) `3` Disabled) and the corresponding key in Local Machine (with the difference that the LSB set to `6` can be used to define an enabled Service) -- Not sure where the telemetry data is stored

Comment: Information is stored in %windir%\system32\WDI\LogFiles\StartupInfo\[current user's SID]_Start. I don't think there's any API for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for listing startup programs. You could use some of options:

1. Scan Registry for startup command line.
2. Leverage [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), as I know it has option to export report.

Answer (score -1):

You could run the powershell:

```
using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
   ps.AddCommand("the command")
       .AddParameter("parname","value");
   ps.Invoke();
   Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
   foreach(var outputObject in result)
   {
       // outputObject contains the result of the powershell script
   }
}
```

Comment: *"I am looking for a way to do so programmatically in C# so I do not need to execute a script to list the startup apps"*